# AJAX cache on server side Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to cache AJAX response on server side instead of fetching data from database each time when client makes request.

```
function post_filter($filter_action,$filter_values) {
    var ajaxurl = SiteInfo.home_url+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": $filter_action, filter_values: $filter_values},
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery("#post-filter-results").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function post_filter($filter_action,$filter_values) {
    var ajaxurl = SiteInfo.home_url+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {"action": $filter_action, filter_values: $filter_values},
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery("#post-filter-results").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so

Answer (score 0):

If you have a php session:

```
$_SESSION["your_key"] = your_response_object
```

example (admin-ajax.php) pseudo-code :

```
if($_SESSION["your_key"])
{
   echo $_SESSION["your_key"];
}else{
   *call DB*
   $_SESSION["your_key"] = *db_response*;
   echo *db_response*;
}
```

Comment: WordPress doesn't use sessions. OP could start one themselves I suppose.